# How to add kernels to histogram in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate this plot in ggplot

```
library(MASS)
data(galaxies)
truehist(galaxies,ymax=0.0002,col="green", main="base R: Triangular Under Smooth")
lines(density(galaxies,kernel="triangular",bw=500),col="red",main="Triangular_Under")
```

So I tried:

```
ggplot() + aes(galaxies) +
  geom_density() +
  stat_density(kernel = "gaussian", bw = 500) +
  labs(title = "ggplot: Triangular Under Smooth")
```

The expected plot I would like should be without dark density plot (only would like to show density line) just like in base plot.

Comment: @d.b Thanks, that works, but how do you make the histogram proportional to the bulges of density line? I would like density line to outline the boundary of histogram.

Comment: have you added   geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))  to your ggplot call?

Comment: @aaumai Yes I did, but still the histogram is way outside. `ggplot() + aes(galaxies) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 1000, boundary = NULL, fill = 'skyblue', color = "black", closed = "left") + # Density
  geom_density() +
  stat_density(kernel = "gaussian", bw = BINWIDTH, fill = NA) +
  labs(title = "ggplot: Triangular Under Smooth")` . Not sure if this is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ggplot() +
    aes(galaxies) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), bins = 15) +
    stat_density(kernel = "gaussian", bw = 500, fill = NA, col = "red") +
    labs(title = "ggplot: Triangular Under Smooth")
```